# Docker How to completely reset MariaDB?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have MariaDB on docker

Trying to setup ssl I managed to completely break my user; I ended up with user duplicates and a new user called `testssl`

I tried resetting everything by deleting my database; deleting the image but nothing works. Every time I connect to the database and list users I get the same old list; `testssl` is still there

Where are those settings stored and how do I reset MariaDB to a completely clean state on my docker?

```
app:
    container_name: app
    image: "${APP_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    build: build/app
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - "${APP_HOST_DIR}:${APP_CONTAINER_DIR}"
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: "mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}
        target: /var/logs/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_CERTS_DIR}
        target: /etc/certs/
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MYSQL_DATABASE}"
      MYSQL_USER: "${MYSQL_USER}"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
```

`.env`

```
MARIADB_DATA_DIR=./build/database/files/database
MARIADB_LOG_DIR=./build/database/files/logs
MARIADB_CERTS_DIR=./build/database/certs
```

Comment: delete `/var/lib/mysql` & `./build/database/files/database`

Comment: How did you get "user duplicates"? If you use [create user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/) this won't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB stores all of its runtime configuration (users, databases, etc.) in its data directory.

You've told your MariaDB container to use the host `build/database/files/database` directory for its data, so resetting the container won't do much since the data is, well, there.

Assuming the container is well-behaved and will initialize the database system if there's nothing in the data directory, you should be able to move that `build/database/files/database` folder to e.g. `build/database/files/database.old`, and create a new empty `build/database/files/database`, then retry.

Comment: The paths are relative in his `.env` file.

Comment: @Marc Fixed already. Haven't had enough coffee yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) you can:

1. Rename the docker volume

From

```
mariadb:
image: mariadb:10.6.11
...
volumes:
  - mysqldataprevious:/var/lib/mysql
...
```

To

```
mariadb:
image: mariadb:10.6.11
...
volumes:
  - mysqldatanew:/var/lib/mysql
...
```

2. Restart docker services

   docker-compose up -d
3. Remove previous volume (optional)

   docker volume prune

This will install a fresh mariadb in the new volume and with **docker volume prune** if your previous volume is not used by another container it will be deleted